# Metrics for multi-class problems in R caret package for various method tags

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

The caret package for R provides a variety of error metrics predominantly aimed at 2-class classification models with limited error metrics. Here is a [multi-class function](http://www.r-bloggers.com/error-metrics-for-multi-class-problems-in-r-beyond-accuracy-and-kappa/) to allow caret:::train to calculate a wide variety of error metrics for multi-class problems.  This works for method tags like knn, rf and gbm with the multiClassSummary function being assigned to summaryFunction of train method in caret. Whereas most of the other method tags are not working. I tried ada, svm, bayesglm and all gave the errors as follows: (Any help to fix this greatly appreciated or is there any generic function similar to twoClassSummary that works for all multi-class predictions?). R Code below:

Here's the multi-class summary function

```
require(compiler)
#Based on caret:::twoClassSummary
multiClassSummary <- cmpfun(function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
  #Load Libraries
  require(Metrics)
  require(caret)
  #Check data
  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"])))
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
  #Calculate custom one-vs-all stats for each class
  prob_stats <- lapply(levels(data[, "pred"]), function(class){
    #Grab one-vs-all data for the class
    pred <- ifelse(data[, "pred"] == class, 1, 0)
    obs <- ifelse(data[, "obs"] == class, 1, 0)
    prob <- data[,class]

    #Calculate one-vs-all AUC and logLoss and return
    cap_prob <- pmin(pmax(prob, .000001), .999999)
    prob_stats <- c(auc(obs, prob), logLoss(obs, cap_prob))
    names(prob_stats) <- c('ROC', 'logLoss')
    return(prob_stats)
  })
  prob_stats <- do.call(rbind, prob_stats)
  rownames(prob_stats) <- paste('Class:', levels(data[, "pred"]))
  #Calculate confusion matrix-based statistics
  CM <- confusionMatrix(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
  #Aggregate and average class-wise stats
  #Todo: add weights
  class_stats <- cbind(CM$byClass, prob_stats)
  class_stats <- colMeans(class_stats)

  #Aggregate overall stats
  overall_stats <- c(CM$overall)
  #Combine overall with class-wise stats and remove some stats we don't want
  stats <- c(overall_stats, class_stats)
  stats <- stats[! names(stats) %in% c('AccuracyNull',
                                       'Prevalence', 'Detection Prevalence')]
  #Clean names and return
  names(stats) <- gsub('[[:blank:]]+', '_', names(stats))
  return(stats)
})
```

R code using caret and train

```
#####------------------------------ada-----------------------------------------------
require('ada')
require('caret')
require('Metrics')

load(iris)
ir.dat <- iris

## Define control function to handle optional arguments for train function
## Models to be assessed based on largest absolute area under ROC curve
cv.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 1, number = 2,
                        summaryFunction = multiClassSummary,
                        classProbs = TRUE)

## note the dot preceding each variable
ada.grid <- expand.grid(.iter = c(50, 100),
                        .maxdepth = c(4, 8),
                        .nu = c(0.1, 1))

ada.tune <- train(Species ~ .,
                  data = ir.dat,
                  method = "ada",
                  metric = 'ROC',
                  trControl = cv.ctrl,
                  tuneGrid = ada.grid)
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'"
In addition: There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: iter= 50, maxdepth=4, nu=0.1 Error in ada.default(x = structure(c(4.7, 5.4, 5, 4.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.7,  : 
  Currently this procedure can not directly handle > 2 class response
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your version of `ada`. Prior to version 2.0-3, the function only handled two classes (notice that the error message comes from `ada.default` and not `train`).

I'm not sure why SVMs and Bayesian glm's would fail. You can always send those to me (or via github)

Max

Comment: Thanks for your response. My ada version now is 2.0-3. But still the error seems to be different this time is:
Error in train.default(x = iris[, -c(5)], y = iris$Species, "ada", tuneGrid = adaGrid,  : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined